# Switching viewable drawing in document for v7 Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to switch from paperspace view to model space view in a dwg loaded in the Forge platform on v7. I think it's supposed to use the BubbleNode, but I can't find any code samples showing. Any ideas how to get the BubbleNode from a loaded document?

I've reviewed: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/migration_guide_v6_to_v7/
and
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/load-a-model/

Trying to piece together some sample code that will do the same thing as step 3 here from v6:https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/basic-viewer/

Answer (score 1):

You can get geometry BubbleNode Array by search method of root BubbleNode with specifying { 'type': 'geometry' } as parameter.

Below is code example for switching viewable.

```
var viewer;
var viewables;
var indexGeom;
var viewdoc;

//Call back for viewer DocumentLoadSuccess 
function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
    viewdoc = doc;
    
    indexGeom = 0;
    viewables = doc.getRoot().search({ 'type': 'geometry' });
    viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables[indexGeom]).then(i => {
        activateUI();
     });
}

//Call back for switch to next view button
function loadNextModel() {
    // Next geometry index. Loop back to 0 when overflown.
    indexGeom = (indexGeom + 1) % viewables.length;
    
    viewer.tearDown();
    
    viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewdoc, viewables[indexGeom]).then(i => {
        activateUI();
    });
}
```

pls. see developer guide '3.Load a Model' chapter.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/load-a-model/